# SSRS Expression SQL Server 2016 - Tablix filtered by two codes now divide them with each other

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder

I have a tablix that I have filtered by two codes and this returns two lines each with the code and the relevant value associated with them.

I would like to write an expression that allows me to divide each value with each other and display just one line with the result.

[image: Codes value]

Expected result:

[image]

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your two values are not in the detail section you can use the following expresseion as your Gorss Profit:

```
=ReportItems!TextboxName500.Value / ReportItems!TextboxName250.Value
```

Where `TextboxName500` is the name of the textbox which holds the value `500`.